# how to solve problem with primary key if i can't insert into table in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to solve problem with primary key if i cant insert into table in sql PLUS?
I mean i need to add more columns

```
CREATE TABLE SETS (
  2  ID NUMBER (4) CONSTRAINT SETS_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  3  COM NUMBER (7,2),
  4  ENAME VARCHAR2(15),
  5  SAL NUMBER(8,2)
  6* );

INSERT INTO SETS VALUES (1, 1, 'COMFORT', 0);
```

1 row inserted.

```
INSERT INTO SETS VALUES (1, 2, ''Progressive', 5000);

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into sets values(1, 2, 'Progressive', 5000)
Error report -
ORA-00001: нарушено ограничение уникальности (AIDAR.SETS_PK)
```

Comment: you need to go for composite primary key.. where combination of two or more columns should be unique.

Comment: uniqueness constraint violated - Primary Key should be unique. In your case you have set first column 'ID' as Primary key

Comment: What does "I mean i need to add more columns" mean? You want to add more columns to the primary key or that you want to add more non-primary key columns to the table or did you mean rows instead of columns? If you want more columns in the primary key then which columns?

Comment: then how do i do like this one before ?!

Comment: select * from comm1;

        ID      COMNO ENAME      DDATE           SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 Engine     20.02.81        900         20
         1          2 Wings      22.02.81      35000         30
         1          3 Battery    09.06.81      84800         20
         1          4 APU        17.11.81       8400         10
         1          5 EECU       03.12.81       8400         20
         1          6 Generator  23.01.82      40000         20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, You need to use composite key for solving your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE SETS (
 ID NUMBER (4),
 COM NUMBER (7,2),
 ENAME VARCHAR2(15),
 SAL NUMBER(8,2),
 CONSTRAINT SETS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID, COM)
 );


INSERT INTO SETS VALUES (1, 1, 'COMFORT', 0);
INSERT INTO SETS VALUES (1, 2, 'Progressive', 5000);


SELECT
    *
FROM
    SETS;

-- Output: --

        ID        COM ENAME                  SAL
---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
         1          1 COMFORT                  0
         1          2 Progressive           5000
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

as you have declared id as a primary key so it will be unique for each row

```
INSERT INTO SETS VALUES (1, 1, 'COMFORT', 0);
INSERT INTO SETS VALUES (2, 2, 'Progressive', 5000);
```

but you have provided the same id for two rows that's why it threw an error. BTW i have edited the 2nd row value and it will work now